# How can I include HTML in a Folium Marker popup?

Tags: python, html, folium

I'd like to include an anchor tag in a Folium Marker popup so that I can click through to another page.

Here's my code:

```
    def poptext(row):
        return "<a href=\"" + row['Feed']  + "\">" + row['Name'] + "</a>"

    map = folium.Map(location=[52.620,-0.264], zoom_start=14)

    df.apply(lambda row: folium.Marker([row['Lat'], row['Lon']],popup=poptext(row)).add_to(map), axis =1)

    map
```

Unfortunately, the HTML doesn't seem to be evaluated. Any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should check the Folium version you are using. 0.2.0 has changed how popups are added, as explained in this issue thread: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/360

Popups now no longer take html automatically but rather one must pass in a `folium.element.IFrame` of the html.

This notebook shows the differences in folium 0.2.0:
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bibmartin/folium/blob/issue288/examples/Popups.ipynb

And, the code would look something like this (found in the notebook above):

```
m = folium.Map([43,-100], zoom_start=4)

html="""
    <h1> This is a big popup</h1><br>
    With a few lines of code...
    <p>
    <code>
        from numpy import *<br>
        exp(-2*pi)
    </code>
    </p>
    """
iframe = folium.element.IFrame(html=html, width=500, height=300)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)

folium.Marker([30,-100], popup=popup).add_to(m)

m
```

NB: The way to create markers, therefore, is no longer `simple_marker` or `circle_marker`, but rather `folium.Marker` or `folium.CircleMarker()`.

The docs have also been (recently?) put up.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed arbitrary HTML using `folium.Html`, with `script=True`. Here is a minimal example which demonstrates this:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map([51.5, -0.25], zoom_start=10)

test = folium.Html('<b>Hello world</b>', script=True)

popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
folium.RegularPolygonMarker(
    location=[51.5, -0.25], popup=popup,
).add_to(m)

m.save('osm.html')
```

Without `script=True`, the string passed to `folium.Html` is escaped and so the HTML markup is visible in the marker popup.

This is documented in the [branca examples page](https://github.com/python-visualization/branca/blob/master/examples/Elements.ipynb). I was using Folium 0.3.0.

Comment: This is out of date for folium 0.5.0

Comment: @MichaelK, I'm on folium 0.7.0 and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the location, URL, and popup text you want.

```py
import folium
f = folium.Figure(width=1000, height=1000)
m=folium.Map([39.067758, -94.573534], zoom_start=25).add_to(f)
pp= folium.Html('<a href="'+ 'give your url here'+'"target="_blank">'+ 'popup text' + '</a>', script=True)
popup = folium.Popup(pp, max_width=2650)
folium.Marker(location=[39.067758, -94.573534], popup=popup).add_to(m)
m=m._repr_html_()
```

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing is that the iframe solution `popup = folium.Popup(iframe)` works for a pop up, but not for a tooltip:

```
html = """<b>your HTML text here</b><br>etc."""
iframe = folium.IFrame(html=html, width=200, height=100)
folium.Marker(location=[37, -99.09], popup=folium.Popup(iframe)) # popup will render html correctly
```

However, substituting popup and Popup from the code above by tooltip and Tooltip, respectively, doesn't work. To make it work, use `render()` method:

```
folium.Marker(location=[37, -99.09], tooltip=folium.Tooltip(iframe.render())) # without the render method, a blank tooltip will appear.
```