# Inserting an URL link in marker's popup in Folium

Tags: python, folium

I want to insert a live url link into my marker's popup in Python Folium but I don't know what class and code I need to use.
my code is a simple one:

```
folium.Marker(location[i], popup="www.dingsbums.lu").add_to(marker_cluster)
```

I just want the url (here 'www.dingsbums.lu') to be a link, not string...

Comment: What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed.

Comment: You need to [properly format your HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp).

Comment: @s.k: Thank you for your comment...I followed your instruction and now my code seems like this: 

url=folium.Html('<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"></a>')                     
folium.Marker(location[i], popup=url).add_to(marker_cluster)

but now I have just an empty popup! Any idea...?

Comment: Do not blindly copy7paste stuff, make sure you understand what href does. Look at the URL.This should answer your question; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185897/how-can-i-include-html-in-a-folium-marker-popup

Comment: @s.k: Thank you for your comment...I followed the link instructions but nothing is changed in my map. Can you help to find and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet should do the job. You can then simply replace the URL *and* the text to be displayed (it *can* actually be the **same** as the URL) with the ones you want.
E.g. `"<a href=https://www.dingsbums.lu>https://www.dingsbums.lu</a>"`

```py
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[49.611622, 6.131935], zoom_start=16,)

tooltip = "Click me!"

marker = folium.Marker(
    [49.61068, 6.13127],
    popup="<a href=https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_Guillaume_II>Place Guillaume II</a>",
    tooltip=tooltip
)

marker.add_to(m)
```

Then, when displaying the map `m` it should show you the following, with a clickable URL in the popup:

[image: Resulting map]
*Notice that the URL is shown on the bottom left of the browser when the mouse is over the corresponding link in the popup.*

More information can be found on the folium documentation: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html

And how the `href` attribute actually works can be discovered here with code samples: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_href.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot. You did it well and now the problem is solved. It seems the problem of my code relied on two issues: first, I'd used "' more than needed. Secondly,It's necessary to give marker's arguments explicitly.