# Modify GeoJSON tooltip format when using Folium to produce a map

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I am producing a map using Folium. I wish to show some data using tooltips when hovering over a country. I can do this using the `folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip()` function and have the following result when hovering over a country of interest.

[image]

I would, however, like to change the default format of this tooltip. I am wondering if there is a way to pass HTML to folium instead, and hence I will be able to show a table in a custom style in this Folium popup/tooltip. For example, I would like to have enough control to show some customisation like this:

[image]

Is this functionality at all possible in Folium? Or do you always have to work with this style for tooltips?

Sharing below my code for the map:

```
frame = folium.Figure(width=1050, height=750)

map_ = folium.Map(location=[35,0], zoom_start=1,
                  tiles=None, crs='EPSG3857', 
                  control_scale=True, attributionControl=False, 
                  min_zoom=2, min_lot=-179,
                  max_lot=179, min_lat=-65, 
                  max_lat=179, max_bounds=True).add_to(frame)

folium.TileLayer(positron,name="Light Map",
                 control=False, max_zoom=6, min_zoom=2, attr='_', noWrap=False).add_to(map_) #, noWrap=True

custom_scale = (df_map['total_mil'].quantile((0,0.8,0.95,0.99,0.999, 1))).tolist()

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=df_map,
    name='Choropleth',
    data=df_map,
    columns=['COUNTRY','total_mil'],
    key_on="feature.properties.COUNTRY",
    fill_color= 'YlGnBu',
    threshold_scale=custom_scale,
    fill_opacity=0.9,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Total number of doses across all vaccine types *Millions',
    smooth_factor=0
).add_to(map_)

style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
                            'color':'#000000', 
                            'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                            'weight': 0.1}
highlight_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#000000', 
                                'color':'#000000', 
                                'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
                                'weight': 0.1}

for i in range(len(df_map)):
    row = df_map.loc[[i]]
    if row.footnote.values == "":
        feature = folium.features.GeoJson(
        row,
        style_function=style_function,
        control=False,
        highlight_function=highlight_function,
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
            fields=[
                'COUNTRY',
                'WHO Region',
                'SFP/AMC',
                'Doses – AZ/SII (indicative distribution)',
                'Doses – AZ/SKBio (indicative distribution)',
                'Doses – Pfizer-BioNTech (exceptional allocation)',
                'update_time',  
            ],
            aliases=[
                "Participant: ",
                "WHO Region: ",
                "SFP/AMC: ",
                'Doses – AZ/SII (indicative distribution): ',
                'Doses – AZ/SKBio (indicative distribution): ',
                'Doses – Pfizer-BioNTech (exceptional allocation): ',
                "Time last updated: ",  
            ],
            style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;")
            )
        )
        map_.add_child(feature)
        map_.keep_in_front(feature)
    else:
        feature = folium.features.GeoJson(
        row,
        style_function=style_function,
        control=False,
        highlight_function=highlight_function,
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
            fields=[
                'COUNTRY',
                'WHO Region',
                'SFP/AMC',
                'Doses – AZ/SII (indicative distribution)',
                'Doses – AZ/SKBio (indicative distribution)',
                'Doses – Pfizer-BioNTech (exceptional allocation)',
                'footnote',
                'update_time',  
            ],
            aliases=[
                "Participant: ",
                "WHO Region: ",
                "SFP/AMC: ",
                'Doses – AZ/SII (indicative distribution): ',
                'Doses – AZ/SKBio (indicative distribution): ',
                'Doses – Pfizer-BioNTech (exceptional allocation): ',
                'Note: ',
                "Time last updated: ",  
            ],
            style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;"),
            )
        )
        map_.add_child(feature)
        map_.keep_in_front(feature)
        
map_
```

Comment: Check this out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/185897/29431

Comment: Very interesting, I will check this out and see how I get on. Thanks.